# Typescript infer return type of an object based on its key

Tags: typescript

What I want to do is very simple, I have a class called `Config`. Inside this class, I have some fields and each one have a different type.

Right now I have a method that basically accepts the field name as the argument and return the value of it, like this:

```js
get(key: Extract<keyof Config, string>): any {
  // this.config is my Config class
  return this.config[key];
}
```

The argument works great, I get auto complete for all the field names in my `Config` class, but based on that, I want to infer the return type of this function. So let's say that the field I'm trying to get has the `DbConfig` type, when I call this `get` method, I want the return to be `DbConfig` as well, and not use any like I did in the example above.

Is that possible? If so, how to do that?

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBkgkm) be ok for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter as a generic type `K`. `K` can then be used to index `Config` for the return type.

```
function get<K extends keyof Config & string>(key: K): Config[K] {
  return config[key]
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBkgkm)